# How to return Joined Tables as Strongly Typed Records in Dapper with F#

Tags: f#, dapper

This library doesn't meet my needs https://github.com/Dzoukr/Dapper.FSharp  so I am wanting to use Dapper directly from F#

I think it is probably that I don't know my F# well enough and how C# translates.

In this page https://www.learndapper.com/relationships  I am trying to model the one to many relationship there

```
var products = await connection.QueryAsync<Product, Category, Product>(sql, (product, category) => {
    product.Category = category;
    return product;
}, 
splitOn: "CategoryId" );
```

This is my attempt  ( broken and not completely finished ) .  How do I "translate" the above into F#?

```
conn.QueryAsync<Order,OrderDetail, Order>(orderSql,(fun (order,orderDetail) -> (order, orderDetail )))
```

( This is not even code that will compile - not even sure where to start )

Comment: To make this into a proper question, can you say what is wrong with/missing from your attempt? (Also, out of curiosity, what's missing in the existing F# wrapper? Maybe the authors would be keen to know so that they can add it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a direct translation of the example into F#:

```
open System.Data.SqlClient
open Dapper

[<CLIMutable>]
type Product =
    {
        ProductId : int
        ProductName : string
        mutable Category : Category
    }

and [<CLIMutable>]
Category =
    {
        CategoryId : int
        CategoryName : string
        Products : Product[]
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use connection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    let sql = "select productid, productname, p.categoryid, categoryname \
               from products p \
               inner join categories c on p.categoryid = c.categoryid"
    let products =
        async {
            return!
                connection.QueryAsync(
                    sql,
                    (fun product category ->
                        product.Category <- category
                        product),
                    splitOn = "CategoryId")
                |> Async.AwaitTask
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously
    printfn "%A" products
    0
```

This is not really idiomatic F# (e.g. due to the mutable field), but it does work.

Comment: Thanks - I guess it is what I asked for.  I really need to have orders with a list of orderitems as a Tuple for each order.